# How to make link and button align in list using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make links and buttons be aligned in list using bootstrap?

I need to make them aligned left with reasonable padding.

Can I do it without CSS and my own classes?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        menu
        &nbsp;
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li>
            <a class="btn btn-link text-left" href=""> 

                Edit
            </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <form action="" method="POST" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/63gn7has/

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the below `CSS class` of bootstrap and try this

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    text-align: left!important;
    padding: 10px!important;
}
```

Comment: Can I do it without CSS and my own classes?